# Add properties dynamically to ViewModel in ExtJs 6

Tags: extjs, viewmodel, dynamically-generated, extjs6

I have a panel with panel where the items in the panel are added dynamically .

I have to attach a view model to the panel.

So how can I add the properties to the viewmodel dynamically in ExtJs 6?

I know how to add formula dynamically .

I looked at the [addMembers](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#static-method-addMember) method. But it doesn't seem to work .

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `viewModel.set('propertyName', propertyValue)`?

Comment: You can refer this for viewmodel [set](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#method-set) and [get](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#method-get)